# Symfony2 functionality similar to View::composer() of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-2.8

I am currently working on a project built with Symfony2.8. I have Laravel background and View::composer() function was life saver in most cases. Especially taking the load of controller coding by having most arguments and data prepared with less parameters passed to a view template. So when a parameter changed, you wouldn't need to go through all your controllers/views to change the arguments but just edit your composer. Long story short, I have quite a few flyout/popovers basically does same thing. It is a big application and these flyouts called in several places with almost same parameters using `with`

Now I need to make changes and add additional data to one of these. I searched a little on google but couldn't find any useful information. Is there any helper functions in Symfony basically does the same thing. I mean rather than going through all call's of this twig template, is there any way to say `whenever this twig is rendered, run this function, and attach some data from it into the template so I can use it in twig.`

Comment: Can't you simply create a Twig filter / function ? More information here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html

Comment: Yeah, but anything passed to twig call will not be available in that function. For instance, I can say larvl `View::composer('user.menu', function($view){ $user_id = $view->user_id; $user = User::find($user_id); $user->last_checkin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $user->save(); $view->fullName = $user->firstName . ' ' .$user->lastName; $view->phone_number = $user->contactInfo->getPhone(); //etc});` then any time I render /view/user/menu.php I have access to `$phone_number` and `$fullName` data, as well as `$user->last_checkin` is updated. then I can call it as `render('user.menu')->with('user_id', 1)`;

Comment: I am not sure if filters give you this sort of functionality?

Comment: Why not let the controller fetch / prepare the data, pass them to the template that will either use or ignore them ?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's been. But a simple change on parameters, then you have to find all controllers renders that twig and modify them. For instance, in above case, if I want to add user's email address, then I have to go through each controller and add that parameter.

Comment: Don't know what your code looks like, but you could perhaps try to wrap this up in a manager or a factory.